# Remove Columns with Grep and Piping

Tags: r

Using the example data:

```
d1<-data.frame(years=c("1","5","10"),group.x=c(1:3),group.b=c(1:3),group.2x=c(1:3))
```

I removed the columns using the following:

```
d2<-d1[,-grep("\\.x$",colnames(d1))]
```

Is there a similar way to accomplish the same using piping instead?

```
d2<- d1 %>%
        filter(!grep("\\.x$",colnames()))
```

returns: `Error: argument "x" is missing, with no default`

The goal is to remove the columns ending with `".x"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In dplyr, `filter` will remove rows and `select` is used to remove/select columns which is what you want here. You can stick with `grep` but dplyr also offers some specialized functions like in this case `ends_with`:

```
library(dplyr)
d1 %>% 
  select(-ends_with(".x"))
#  years group.b group.2x
#1     1       1        1
#2     5       2        2
#3    10       3        3
```

Take a look at `help("select")` to find out more about other "special functions" you can use inside `dplyr::select`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply leave d1 in the select as follows:

```
d1 %>%
   select(-grep("\\.x$",colnames(d1)))
```

Results in :

```
years  group.b group.2x
 1       1        1
 5       2        2
10       3        3
```